# Consuming assemblies enforcing claims-based authorization from console applications

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-identity

I'm currently introducing (into an existing application) a custom permissions system which maps roles provided by claims (coming from WSFed-based OWIN auth in a web app) to permissions defined in the application itself.

Currently, the plan is to back the permissions system directly onto the thread principal.

These permissions are validated:

- In the web UI
- In the business layer (in case of future alternative UIs).

However, one thing that is currently unaccounted for is that there is a console application running as a scheduled task which consumes the same business layer classes as the web app (same assembly reference). The app runs under a local Windows user in a separate domain, which does not have the required roles (and thus will fail to authorize).

I can see a few workarounds to this problem:

1. Duplicate the roles in the Windows machine and assign to the system user under which the console app runs.
2. Modify the console app to explicitly add the claims to the identity used.
3. Modify the permissions system to have some kind of override and/or inject a "dud" permissions system from the console app.

None of these seem like particularly elegant solutions. Given that, my question is simply: is there a canonical approach in the context of Identity to authorization in this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting question with no real canonical answer that I'm aware of.

I would go with the either 1 or 2, depending on your situation. If going through with the authentication logic for your clients, your console app is just another client and it needs to have permissions to do stuff in your system. Modifying your permissions system just for a client can open security holes and sounds like a hack - against logic for clients with permissions.

Now between 1 and 2 - this is down to the situation you are working with. If the client is to be deployed multiple times or by your customers, for deployment simplicity I would hack the command line app and add required claims to the principal there.

If your command-line client is for private consumption and is not to be deployed multiple times, the easiest would be to have a separate domain user with all the required permissions on the user and run the app from the user. This will decouple permissions from the app and will make your life easier if you need to change permissions on the app user without code changes in the command-line app.

These are pure my speculation and I hope there will be other opinions.

Comment: Ultimately I decided that simpler was better. I set up my permissions service so an `IPrincipal` could be injected into the ctor and injected a fake principal with full privileges from the console app.

Comment: @AntP That is a good example of "idiomatic is not always the best". Glad you found a good solution for your problem.